# How to make a discord bot react to every message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that will react to every message with a simple pigeon emoji, how can I do this?

Below is the start, but I don't know if it works:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

from apikeys import Bot Token

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Pigebot fliegt Los!")
    print("-------------------")

initial_extensions = []

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs")
    if filename.endswith(".py")
        initial_extension.append("cogs." + filename[:-3])

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            for extension in initial_extensions:
                client.load_extension(extension)

client.run(Bot Token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_message` event :

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.add_reaction('emoji name')
```

Comment: Make sure to also enable message_content intents